# Reference undefined to functions in python-dev header

Tags: python, c, gcc, linker

I'm trying to embedding some Python code into C; It's the first time I do a thing like that.

Here is the simple code of my first attempt copied by a guide on internet:

```
#include <Python.h>
void exec_pycode(const char* code)
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString(code);
  Py_Finalize();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    exec_pycode(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

So I've installed python3.4-dev package.

Then for having info for the linker I typed:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs python3
```

Then I tried to compile my code:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o main -I /usr/local/include/python3.4m  -L /usr/local/lib -lpython3.4m main.c
```

(according the command before)

but this is the result:

```
/tmp/ccJFmdcr.o: in function "exec_pycode":
main.c:(.text+0xd): reference undefined to "Py_Initialize"
main.c:(.text+0x1e): reference undefined to "PyRun_SimpleStringFlags"
main.c:(.text+0x23): reference undefined to "Py_Finalize"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It would seem that there is a problem with linking phase, but I can't understend where is the problem seeing that i've passed to the linker the exact paths of the header and of the library. How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reordering your compilation command, such that all linking options are specified *after* your C source files:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o main -I /usr/local/include/python3.4m main.c \
  -L /usr/local/lib -lpython3.4m
```

Comment: yes I've resolved the previous problem but now I've that problem:
/usr/local/lib/libpython3.4m.a(pytime.o): in function "_PyTime_ObjectToTime_t":
/home/matteo/Scrivania/Python-3.4.3/Python/pytime.c:212: undefined reference to "ceil"
/home/matteo/Scrivania/Python-3.4.3/Python/pytime.c:214: undefined reference to "floor"
/usr/local/lib/libpython3.4m.a(pytime.o): in function "_PyTime_ObjectToDenominator":
/home/matteo/Scrivania/Python-3.4.3/Python/pytime.c:173: undefined reference to "ceil"  ...(and all other maths functions)
So I tried to recompile adding -lm but I didn't resolve the problem :/

Comment: @MatteoArella Where did you add `-lm`? Try a few different places - before `-lpython3.4m` and after, and see which one works. If neither works, try running `python-config --ldflags` in a terminal and use those as the linker flags.

Comment: Note that you may have to change the order of flags in the `python-config` output - if it doesn't work try moving `-lpython3.4m` after all the `-L` flags and before all the `-l` flags.